# Animate the height change of a relativelayout

Tags: android-edittext, android-animation, android-relativelayout

I have a relativelayout, within is an edittext. 
The relativelayout has the change height like the edittext with "wrap_content".
When i write in the edittext more lines, the relativelayout expands to the bottom, but with no animation.
Now:
How do i animate this change of height when i type?

Here are two screenshots with the change. From this:
[image]

It should animate to this, while im typing:
[image]

The white background behind the edittext is the relativelayout, that should expand with an animation.

Comment: Have you tried setting animateLayoutChanges to true? http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html

Comment: @Whitney does not work